# How to force layout recalculation after one of its children is resized using CSS?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets, qlayout

I have a dialog box with two widgets (which are actually vertical layouts themselves), and a spacer in the middle, arranged as a horizontal layout, like so (layout "lines" are red):

[image]

I also have a global stylesheet that's loaded and parsed at runtime. The trouble is, this stylesheet changes the height of some widgets in the left layout, but the main layout doesn't seem to take that into consideration, and so when the application is running it looks like this:

[image]

My understanding is that the main layout is resized to compensate for the extra space needed to accommodate the widgets in the left layout, but the right layout is then not resized to fit that extra space in its parent, which looks ugly. I'm using the default size constraint in all layouts.

What can I do to force the right layout to resize itself?

Comment: That's the most curious "C++" question I have ever seen.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well, I just wanted to specify that I'm using C++, not Python, in this application if a potential answer were to include some code I could use. Though you're probably right :P

Comment: It would be useful to see some code how that dialog is created and example of qss that is used.